# Appending my state array in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
clickHandler(type) {



    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.pokemon.length ; i++) {

            //console.log(this.state.pokemon[i]);
            //Do something temp1.types[0].type.name
            for(var j = 0; j < this.state.pokemon[i].types.length; j++) {

                if(this.state.pokemon[i].types[j].type.name == type.target.value) {
                    var toBeAppened = this.state.filteredPokemon.slice()
                    toBeAppened.push(this.state.pokemon[i])
                    this.setState({
                        filteredPokemon: this.state.filteredPokemon

                    })


                }


            }

    }
    console.log(this.state.filteredPokemon) 
}
```

This function is a handler of appending a specific part of data of my state array "pokemon" to another state array called "filteredPokemon".

After I run this, my filteredPokemon is just an empty array.
I checked that this is valid by debugging with console.log, but it just does not append properly into my "filteredPokemon"

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you appending the correct item?   `this.setState({
                        filteredPokemon: this.state.filteredPokemon

                    })`

Comment: actually yeah, i changed it from the code above, but it still does not work. To further clarfiy, it does append the item, but it does not reset it every time I click different buttons

Comment: For example, clicking a fire button should add three items in my case [charmander, charlizard, charwizard], but it keeps appending [charwizard] only to the filteredPokemon. And when I try to select a different button, it should reset the one it had before, but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how are you handling your data. what's the pokemon object like? To me the easiest way to handle your data and filter your pokemons should be something like this:

```
pokemon : {
   name: 'Charmander',
   type: 'Fire',
   (...)
}
```

That way filtering your array of pokemons should be pretty straightforward:

```
clickHandler(type) {
    const { pokemon } = this.state;
    const filteredPokemon = [];

    pokemon.forEach((_pokemon) => {
      if (_pokemon.type === type) {
        filteredPokemon.push(_pokemon);
      }
    });

    this.setState({ filteredPokemon });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make an assumption that, the problem is, that you are setting wrong variable into state. You should set `toBeAppended` array instead of

```
clickHandler(type) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.pokemon.length; i++) {
    //console.log(this.state.pokemon[i]);
    //Do something temp1.types[0].type.name
    for (var j = 0; j < this.state.pokemon[i].types.length; j++) {
      if (this.state.pokemon[i].types[j].type.name == type.target.value) {
        var toBeAppened = this.state.filteredPokemon.slice();
        toBeAppened.push(this.state.pokemon[i]);
        // you are adding an item to toBeAppened array, therefore you should set this array into state
        this.setState({
          filteredPokemon: toBeAppened
        });
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(this.state.filteredPokemon);
}
```

The second issue, which could be, is that `types` array of every pokemon is empty, therefore the second nested loop is not invoking.

Try to debug your `if` condition as well, probably `this.state.pokemon[i].types[j].type.name == type.target.value` expression is returning false